# GridFS and atomic updates

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

I'm considering to use MongoDB GridFS to store and retrieve images but reading official documentation (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/) I coudn't understand following part:

> Do not use GridFS if you need to update the content of the entire file atomically. As an alternative you can store multiple versions of each file and specify the current version of the file in the metadata. You can update the metadata field that indicates “latest” status in an atomic update after uploading the new version of the file, and later remove previous versions if needed.

What does it means when they says: "update the content of the entire file atomically"? What if I need to update a stored image? What happens to stored file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GridFS splits the contents of a file into chunks (so that each chunk does not exceed the 16 MB document size limit).

As the linked documentation says, GridFS does not support transactions. Without transactions, only individual operations on a document are atomic, but GridFS may perform operations on multiple documents which would not be atomic.

Additionally, file metadata and file contents are stored separately, and again would not be written atomically.

> What if I need to update a stored image?

You can insert a new image and then (atomically) update other documents to reference the newly uploaded image.

Comment: Hey Oleg, thank you for your clarification. Ok, just to make sure I got right understanding. There isn't an operation to update a document, you may just insert and delete it, so to update a document the only way is to insert a new one and then update references?

Comment: GridFS API works with files (or streams), not with documents as that term is used elsewhere in MongoDB.

Comment: Yes, it is files, not document in GridFS's terminology. So my understanding from first comment is correct?

Comment: There is no update operation in GridFS that I am aware of.